# Swift / Xcode leaks with pure value type array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

Anyone could help with this code

```swift
import UIKit

private enum Letters {
    case a
    case b
    case c
    case d
    case e
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var letters: [Letters] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        letters = [.a, .b, .c, .d, .e]
    }

}
```

I don't know if *Swift* it's the problem or *Xcode* alerts a false positive but when I ram this code occurs a leak.

[image: Letters contiguous array leak]

I performed tests with *pure value type* as **enum** and **structs** and the same error occurs. But when I test with *reference type* as **class** works like a charm as follow.

```swift
import UIKit

private class Letters {
    static let a = LettersA()
    static let b = LettersB()
    static let c = LettersC()
    static let d = LettersD()
    static let e = LettersE()
}

private class LettersA: Letters {
}

private class LettersB: Letters {
}

private class LettersC: Letters {
}

private class LettersD: Letters {
}

private class LettersE: Letters {
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var letters: [Letters] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        letters = [.a, .b, .c, .d, .e]
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you also show the code that works (with a reference type)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What did you do before seeing the memory leak? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Sweeper if your run this code and click on memory graph your can this error

Comment: @Sweeper have you ever seen this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved in Xcode 10.3 [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_12_4_release_notes)

```
   Resolved an issue where running an app in iOS 12.2 or later under the 
   Leaks instrument resulted in random numbers of false-positive leaks 
   for every leak check after the first one in a given run. You might
   still encounter this issue in Simulator, or in macOS apps when using
   Instruments from Xcode 10.2 and later. (48549361)
```